# Showing/hiding hint text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a `.js` file with the following in it:

```
$('.emailhinttext').hide();
$('select').change(function() {
if ($(this).val() == 'For yourself, your church, school, a friend etc...') {
    $('.emailhinttext').show();
}
if ($(this).val() == 'A Charity like Oxfam, Marie Curie or Help the Aged') {
    $('.emailhinttext').hide();
}
});
```

It does have a couple of other things in it (Should that matter?) and I include the file in the header of my page along with jQuery.

my html is:

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="I am raising money for">I am raising money for...</label>
    <select name="data[I am raising money for]" id="I am raising money for">
        <option value="0">A Charity like Oxfam, Marie Curie or Help the Aged</option>
        <option value="1">For yourself, your church, school, a friend etc...</option>
</select></div>
<div class="input text required">
    <label for="UserEmail">Email&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="emailhinttext">*Please use the same email as your paypal account</div></label>
    <input name="data[User][email]" type="text" maxlength="255" id="UserEmail" />
</div>
```

It doesn't work even though on jsfiddle something really similar works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do load your javascript? Make sure that it's executed AFTER the html have been loaded. Typically inside `$(function() { HERE })` or in `$(document).ready`

Comment: You can use [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) to practice and learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The val() is either 0 or 1 (the value of value attribute), and not the text inside the option tag. So changing to `if ($(this).val() == 1)` will resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've changed it to 1 and 0 (and also '1' and '0') but that doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: check your assesration (alert($(this).val()). This way you'll see also if change handler is triggered at all.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: $('select').change(function() { alert($(this).val()); }

Comment: Hi, thanks. When I do that the value shows 0 or 1 according to which value I select. So how come it doesn't show the div like it meant to?

Comment: @CrazySarah let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1302/discussion-between-darhazer-and-crazy-sarah)

Answer (score 1):

Check a few things, you reference jQuery before your script, also make sure your script is wrapped in the document.ready call like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code goes here
});
```

Any of that help?

Comment: Oh deary deary me. I thought I did have it wrapped with that but turns out that the closing }); wasn't after it. oops. That only half helps though. The div that's meant to be hidden in the first place now is hidden, but it doesn't appear when I change the select value. I have done what the poster below suggested changing the values to 0 and 1 but that doesn't make a difference

Comment: After your select.change line, add alert($(this).val()); That will help you test exactly what value is selected. I think another solution is to use "else" as your second condition instead of 2 "if" statements back to back.

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite a lot; your jQuery code isn't executed when the page is loaded. You need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.emailhinttext').hide();

    $('select').change(function() 
    {
        if ($(this).val() == 'For yourself, your church, school, a friend etc...') 
        {
            $('.emailhinttext').show();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == 'A Charity like Oxfam, Marie Curie or Help the Aged') 
        {
            $('.emailhinttext').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

This will execute the jQuery when the document has loaded, instead of having it just sit in the DOM not doing much.